# How to retrieve custom study value from a strategy?

Tags: pine-script

I want to use some public studies/indicators in my strategy without actually adding their source code to my strategy, any idea how to do it?

Kind of looking something like this

```
ta.externalstudy("third-party study",param1,param2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if what you are looking for is part of a [library](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Libraries.html). Or you can publish a library yourself and then use it in your script.

You can check out [this](https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/library/) page for some of the published libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I already use the **library**; my question is more on public studies/indicators created by other people's end.  I want to avoid code copying.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to copy their code. There is no other way.

Comment: Thanks, I hope they will add a way; it is taking so much time for no reason 
In case anyone likes the idea, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TradingView/comments/wqv3t3/allow_access_to_public_indicatorsstudies_from_a/) is a way to upvote it as a feature request